# Silverlight Gradient Border Effect

Tags: silverlight, effects

This was done in Photoshop:
[photoshop http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/333777824b.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/333777824b.png)

The white box I would create using a Silverlight `Border`. How would I then create the dropshadow kind of effect. As you can see it is a bit different from the standard dropshadow.

Would Shazzam help achieve this?

**Edit:** Graeme got me looking in the right direction. I ended up using [this](http://architecture-blog.rdacorp.com/2008/10/creating-drop-shadows-in-silverlight.html) solution which I found following this path:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/13710.aspx
http://10rem.net/blog/2008/04/03/simple-xaml-drop-shadows-in-silverlight-2

Thanks Graeme!

Comment: No idea what "Shazzam" is - isn't that a music app?

Comment: Shazzam is a Pixel Shader tool http://shazzam-tool.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a second border. Give it a LinearGradient brush for the stroke and increase the thickness.

Answer (score 1):

ondesertverge, there is a control which adds glow effect in Blacklight open-source project:
http://blacklight.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Sergei. Looks like an awesome project I'll look into soon.

Answer (score 0):

For this effect, "Glow" can be used but I have noticed that silverlight and wpf had glow effect in earlier version but i cant find it. You can use Glow to give dark color shadow effect as well.